# Differential Form, Closed And Exact

Tags: calculus

I am taking my last course in calculus and we have started with differential form and linear differential form, I have encountered some definitions that I do not understand

1. $dx_i$ will symbol the differential form defined by $d(x_i)(x,\xi)=\xi_i$ where $\xi=(\xi_1,...,\xi_n)$

What is this $dx_i$? shouldn't is be $d(x_i)(x,\xi)=\frac{\partial x_0}{\partial x_i}\xi_i$ ?

2. A form $\omega$ will be called exact is there is a function such that $df=\omega$

Is there a simple example I can understand what that mean?

3. What is a closed differential form?

Comment: Your edit made the post miss a lot of context.

Comment: If this comes from a textbook, I'd give the name and author.  A careful author will provide definitions for the notation and terminology you are asking about.  As the treatments can vary somewhat from book to book, providing more context is important to helping you.

Answer (score 1):

If $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable on the open region $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n,$ then the *differential* of $f$ at $(x_1, \ldots, x_n),$ denoted $df(x_1, \ldots, x_n),$ where $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \Omega,$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ defined by
$$df(x_1, \ldots, x_n)(\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \xi_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \xi_n.$$

Thus $df$ is a linear map valued field.

1. $dx_i$ is the differential of $x_i,$ i.e.
   $$
   dx_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n)(\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n) 
   = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_1} \xi_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_n} \xi_n
   = \xi_i,
   $$
   since only the term with $\partial x_i / \partial x_i$ does not vanish.
2. Assume that $\vec F = (F_i)$ is a vector field, and let $\omega = \sum_{i=1}^{n} F_i \, dx^i.$ Then $\omega$ is *exact* if there exists a scalar field $\phi$ such that $\omega = d\phi = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} dx^i,$ i.e. if $F_i = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i},$ i.e. if $\vec F = \nabla \phi.$
3. A differential form $\omega$ is *closed* if $d\omega = 0.$ For example, let $\omega$ be as in point 2. Then 
   $$
   d\omega 
   = d\sum_{i=1}^{n} F_i \, dx^i
   = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} dx^j \wedge dx^i
   = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{j} \left( \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} \right) dx^j \wedge dx^i
   $$
   where the last equality is due to antisymmetry of $dx^j \wedge dx^i.$ One can see that $d\omega = 0$ if and only if 
   $$\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_i} = 0$$
   for all $i,j = 1, \ldots, n.$ In 3 dimensions this is when the curl of $\vec F$ vanishes.